Hypercenter of a ring forms a subring of $R$
Hernstein said that hypercenter $T(R)=\lbrace a\in R ~|~ ax^n=x^na, n=n(x,a)\ge 1, ~for~all~ x \in R\rbrace$ forms a subring of $R$. But I am unable to prove it.
Proof: Let $a,b \in T(R)$, now we have to prove $a-b \in T(R)$. Since $a,b \in T(R)$ it means
$ax^p=x^pa$ for some integer $p$ and $bx^q=x^qb$ for some integer $q$.
Now take $(a-b)x^t$, what $t$ I should choose to prove the required result.

I am not sure but what if you take $t=pq$

Here's a fairly formal proof, formalizing @Muhammad's suggestion in the comments:
To show that $T(R)$ is a subring, we need to demonstrate two things: That it is a subgroup under addition, and that it is closed under multiplication.
Suppose that $a, b\in T(R)$, and let $x\in R$ be arbitrary. Set $p=n(x, a)$ and $q=n(x, b)$. Then we can write $(a-b)x^{pq}=(a-b)x^px^{p(q-1)}=x^p(a-b)x^{p(q-1)}$, “transferring over” factors of $x^p$. Completing this process $q$ times, we have:
\begin{equation}x^{pq}(a-b) = x^{pq}a-x^{pq}b = ax^{pq} - bx^{pq} = (a-b)x^{pq},\end{equation} by the distributive axiom of a ring, and the fact that both $a$ and $b$ are in the hypercenter. This demonstrates that $(a-b)$ is in $T(R)$ with $n(a-b, x)\leq n(a, x)n(b, x)$, showing that $T(R)$ is an additive subgroup of $R$ by what is sometimes called the ''one step'' subgroup test.
Now note that if $a, b\in T(R)$, we have $x^n(ab) = ax^nb = abx^n$ by associativity and the definition of $T(R)$, so $T(R)$ is closed under multiplication as well, and is thus a subring. This proves the theorem.

How can you write $ax^{pq}=x^{pq}a$, we do not know it, we only know about $ax^p=x^pa$

Do my edits address this? We can “transfer over” $x^{pq}$ in groups of $x^p$

Yes it is okay now @Skyler
